# My function display_board () keeps repeating

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Help, every time i run this tic tac toe code, the display_board() keeps appearing

```py
def game():
    while True:
        clear_board()
        player1_name()
        player2_name()
        player_type()
        turn = first_player()
        play_game = input('Are you ready to play? (Yes/No)')
        if play_game.lower()[0] == 'y':
            game_on = True
        else:
            game_on = False
            
        while game_on:
            if turn == (name1):
                print((name1) + ", It's your turn!")
                display_board()
                
                if type1 == 'X':
                    choosexposition()

                    if wingamex():
                        display_board()
                        print((name1) + ", you have won the game!")
                        game_on = False
                    else:
                        if fullspace_check():
                            display_board()
                            print("It's a draw!")
                            break
                        else:
                            turn = (name2)
                            
                elif type1 == 'O':
                    chooseoposition()

                    if wingameo():
                        display_board()
                        print((name1) + ", you have won the game!")
                        game_on = False
                    else:
                        if fullspace_check():
                            display_board()
                            print("It's a draw!")
                            break
                        else:
                            turn = (name2)
            else:
                print((name2) + ", It's your turn!")
                display_board()
                
                if type2 == 'X':
                    choosexposition()
                    
                    if wingamex():
                        display_board()
                        print((name2) + ", you have won the game!")
                        game_on = False
                    else:
                        if fullspace_check():
                            display_board()
                            print("It's a draw!")
                            break
                        else:
                            turn = (name1)
                            
                elif type1 == 'O':
                    chooseoposition()

                    if wingameo():
                        display_board()
                        print((name2) + ", you have won the game!")
                        game_on = False
                    else:
                        if fullspace_check():
                            display_board()
                            print("It's a draw!")
                            break
                        else:
                            turn = (name1)
                        
        if replay() == True:
            pass
```

and it runs this:

Player 1, What's your name? Tic
You got that correct? (Yes/No)Y
Alright then!
Player 2, What's your name? Tac
You got that correct? (Yes/No)Y
Alright then!
Tic, do you want to be X or O?X
Tac is O
Tac, You go first!
Are you ready to play? (Yes/No)Y
Tac, It's your turn!

```
|‾‾‾|‾‾‾|‾‾‾|
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
Tac, It's your turn!
|‾‾‾|‾‾‾|‾‾‾|
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
Tac, It's your turn!
|‾‾‾|‾‾‾|‾‾‾|
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
Tac, It's your turn!
```

Comment: dont worry about the board

Comment: it works fine in jupyter note book

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean, since you did put ```display_board()``` throughout the code.

Comment: You're using ```print((name1) + ", It's your turn!")``` (and others)  without giving the players any way to enter their moves.

Comment: how can i make the display_board and print((name2) + ", It's your turn!") run only once?

Comment: i made a funcion

Comment: i made a function for variables name1 & name2

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your original post and not in comments.

Comment: so how can  i make the display_board and print((name2) + ", It's your turn!") run only once